# use jquery/ajax for Getting ALL Youtube Video ID's for a given user

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem in getting all Youtube Video id's.

I'm trying to get all video id's from from Youtube for a given Youtube username, but the problem is that youtube allows only 50 results at a time . What is the best way to get all Youtube id.
this is the code I have now:

```
<div id="video"></div>
<script>
   function getYouTubeAllInfo() {
       $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Revision3/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&start-index=1&max-results=49', 
       function(data){
           $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){
               var id = item['id']['$t'];
               id = id.replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/",""); 
               $("#video").append('<div id="'+id+'"> ['+id+'] ['+i+'] ');
               $("#video").append('</div>');
           });
       }); 
   }

 $(document).ready(function () {
     getYouTubeAllInfo();
 });    


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get the count of videos, you can do something like this:

```
int currentIndex = 1
int count = GET_COUNT_SOMEHOW;
while (currentIndex < count) {
           $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Revision3/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&start-index=' + currentIndex + '&max-results=49', 
           function(data){
               $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){
                   var id = item['id']['$t'];
                   id = id.replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/",""); 
                   $("#video").append('<div id="'+id+'"> ['+id+'] ['+i+'] ');
                   $("#video").append('</div>');
       });
   }); 
    currentIndex += 50;
}
```

Comment: Be careful.  This approach can fire hundreds of ajax requests at the same time.

Comment: Hi Sebastián; you were correct about the ajax requests . is there a nice way to get this info by queueing the reqests ?

Comment: Sebastián, I ran the code but it goes into a infinite loop showing the same 50 results again and agian. any advise . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call it recursively until there are no more results:

```
function getYouTubeAllInfo(perpage, page, recursive) {
   // $("#video").append('<div> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Revision3/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&start-index='+(((page-1)*perpage)+1)+'&max-results='+perpage+' </div>');  //debug
   $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/Revision3/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&start-index='+(((page-1)*perpage)+1)+'&max-results='+perpage, 
   function(data){
       $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){
           var id = item['id']['$t'];
           id = id.replace("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/",""); 
           $("#video").append('<div id="'+id+'"> ['+id+'] ['+i+'] </div>');
           //alert(page+perpage-2);
           if(i == perpage-2 && recursive){
               getYouTubeAllInfo(perpage, page+1, recursive);
           }
       });
   }); 
}

       getYouTubeAllInfo(49, 1, true);
```

You can test it here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Xemgz/8/

It's a slow process, this user has many videos.

Comment: hi Sebastián ; you were correct about the ajax requests . is there a nice way to queuue the requests ?

Comment: Sebastián, I ran the code but it goes into a infinite loop showing the same 50 results again and agian. any advise . thanks

Comment: hi Sebastián; I ran the code ! thanks it is perfect. 
How can I :
1. grab all the id and pass it to a php variable ?
2. how can I grab the id along other information from youtube and updat mysql  table ?



thanks

Comment: If you need your PHP server to know theese ID's you should probably get them from PHP directly instead of using Javascript, I guess.

Comment: hi Sebastián; the problem with php is that it skips over some enteries when I use the $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=youtubeuser&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc"), true); or when I use Curl .