# Get IDs of all youtube vides containing a particular string

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I wish to get all the titles of Youtube videos on a topic. Topic can be a string. Let's say "Fifa 2014". Can I get IDs of all the videos whose title/tag contain this string? I searched on SO but could only find this:

1. [use jquery/ajax for Getting ALL Youtube Video ID's for a given user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123088/use-jquery-ajax-for-getting-all-youtube-video-ids-for-a-given-user)

I am not a PHP/JAVASCRIPT guy but I can learn if necessary. I just wish to know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is using api version 2 which is deprecated. Use api version 3. 
Also, your example is limited to videos of 1 user. You can get all videos of 1 channel and filter on the data returned. I don't know if there is a limit here.
However, using a search request for videos of multiple channels, do have a limit, which is 500 at this moment. Use some variations of the same request and filtering on duplicates in order to exceed this limit a little bit.

API VERSION 3:
See for start: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started

For search (for example, using the parameters: order, publishedAfter and publishedBefore):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

For a try:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it

For an example (php, javascript and others):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#examples